# ".Replace" in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, xpath, google-apps-script

The following is a line from a example code which will extract data from a url using xpath:

xpath = xpath.replace("/html/","").replace("/tbody","","g");

(where xpath may be something like: "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/table/tbody/td/tr/td[2]/a";

I don't understand why the second ".replace" can have three values? What does the "g" mean?

Is the above equivalent to the following?

xpath = xpath.replace("/html/","");

xpath = xpath.replace("/tbody","","g");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) about the `replace` method, you will notice the syntax is as follows :
[image]

and they describe the last parameter like below :

**flags** : 
Note - The flags argument is a non-standard Mozilla extension. A string specifying a combination of regular expression flags. The use of the flags parameter in the String.replace method is non-standard. Instead of using this parameter, use a RegExp object with the corresponding flags. The value of this parameter if it is used should be a string consisting of one or more of the following characters to affect the operation as described:

g:
global match

i:
ignore case

m:
match over multiple lines

y:
sticky

In your code you use `g` , meaning it's a global replacement, replacing every occurrence in the string.(note that this is non standard and that they recommend using the flag in the regular expression itself, [see doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions))

I'd recommend to read the whole article as it is very clear and helps to understand what you can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a RegEx global modifier.  Perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).  All occurances of "/tbody" will be replaced, not just the first one.